# Find indices in one DataFrame column of each match in a second column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match

I have a DataFrame that looks this way:

[image]

I want to find, for each row, the index of the match between the current row's `previous` value in the `current` column, such that I get a new series called `idx_previous` as follows:

[image]

So far I have tried using the Pandas.Series.where() function to see the location. If I do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'current':['a','aa','ab','aaa','aab','aba','abb'],
    'previous':['','a','a','aa','aa','ab','ab']})

df['idx_previous'] = ''
for previous in df.previous[1:]:
    df.loc[df.previous==previous, 'idx_previous'] = df.loc[df.current == 
previous].index[0]
```

I can get what I want, but this seems like an un-elegant workaround. Is there some method that would be better suited for this task? Thanks.

Note: `previous` is, by definition, the string in `current` to element `N-1`. And `current` is made up of all unique values.

Comment: Umm... is current unique? So if we added a `current=zzz previous=a` - and there was an `current=a previous=b` before that - what's expected?

Comment: @JonClements `current` is unique, yes. `previous` is the string in `current` to element `N-1`

Comment: What are you planning to do with these index values? What’s your higher level goal? Maybe something like ‘pd.Series.shift()’ would be useful?

Comment: You don't even need the column `previous`, just use `df['current'][:-1]`. This question doesn't seem to be a reusable resource.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a series `s` which reverses the mapping of `df['current']`. Then use this with `pd.Series.map`:

```
s = pd.Series(df.index, index=df['current'].values)
df['idx_previous'] = df['previous'].map(s)

print(df)

  current previous  idx_previous
0       a                    NaN
1      aa        a           0.0
2      ab        a           0.0
3     aaa       aa           1.0
4     aab       aa           1.0
5     aba       ab           2.0
6     abb       ab           2.0
```

This solution relies on the values of `df['current']` being unique, otherwise your requirement is ambiguous. In addition, the existence of non-mapped values, e.g. the first row, result in `NaN` and force `df['idx_previous']` to be upcasted to `float`, since `NaN` is a `float` value.